# Pine script 5: MA cross over (Tradingview)

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to have an overlay on 2 Moving Averages when they cross each other, sth. like here shown:

[image]

But it's not working, now getting an error "end of line w/o line continuation"... Any ideas? Thank you!

```
//@version=5
indicator("Moving Average Cross", shorttitle="MA Cross", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
    type == "SMA" ? ta.sma(source, length) :
     type == "EMA" ? ta.ema(source, length) :
     type == "SMMA (RMA)" ? ta.rma(source, length) :
     type == "WMA" ? ta.wma(source, length) :
     type == "VWMA" ? ta.vwma(source, length) :
     na

show_ma1   = input(true   , "MA №1", inline="MA #1")
ma1_type   = input.string("SMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #1", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma1_source = input(close  , ""     , inline="MA #1")
ma1_length = input.int(20     , ""     , inline="MA #1", minval=1)
ma1_color  = input(#f6c309, ""     , inline="MA #1")
ma1 = ma(ma1_source, ma1_length, ma1_type)
plot(show_ma1 ? ma1 : na, color = ma1_color, title="MA №1")

show_ma2   = input(true   , "MA №2", inline="MA #2")
ma2_type   = input.string("SMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #2", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma2_source = input(close  , ""     , inline="MA #2")
ma2_length = input.int(50     , ""     , inline="MA #2", minval=1)
ma2_color  = input(#fb9800, ""     , inline="MA #2")
ma2 = ma(ma2_source, ma2_length, ma2_type)
plot(show_ma2 ? ma2 : na, color = ma2_color, title="MA №2")

longCond = ta.crossover(ma1 > ma2)
shortCond = ta.crossunder(ma1 < ma2)

plotshape(series=longCond, title="Long", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color.green, text="LONG", size=size.normal)
plotshape(series=shortCond, title="Short", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color.red, text="SHORT", size=size.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using argument names in a function, you must keep stating the argument names from that point on.

In your case, you immediately use `series=`. After this parameter, all following parameters must have their argument name specified. It is missing for the `color`.

```
plotshape(series=longCond, title="Long", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="LONG", size=size.normal)
plotshape(series=shortCond, title="Short", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, text="SHORT", size=size.normal)
```

Note: You probably want to do:

```
longCond = ta.crossover(ma1, ma2)
shortCond = ta.crossunder(ma1, ma2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "end of line w/o line continuation" error has to do with the spacing or tab spacing for the multi-lines in a multi-line function.

in your ma function, your "SMA" line is one space back to far OR all the other lines are 1 space forward to far.

I know... it's silly how that small spacing error does that... LoL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).